# Want to get lowest value from sql

Tags: php, mysql

In my database there are 5 values: 50, 75, 95, 125 and 200. When I query the minimum value I get 125, but I should get 50.

Here is my code:

```
$result_upTICKET = mysql_query("SELECT ID, EID, COMMISSION, MIN(PRICE) as PRICE FROM `tickets` WHERE EID='$EID_UPcoMing' AND STATUS='1'");

while($row_upTICKET = mysql_fetch_array($result_upTICKET))
{
    $PRICE_upTICKET= $row_upTICKET['PRICE'];
    $COMMISSION_upTICKET= $row_upTICKET['COMMISSION'];
}
```

What did I get wrong?

Comment: you should write your min() as a where condition

Comment: ....... LIMIT n :D

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: is 125 the minimum of the data results? If so then the result is expected. `MIN` only operates on the result set not the entire table.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT ID, EID, COMMISSION, PRICE FROM `tickets` WHERE EID='$EID_UPcoMing' AND STATUS='1' ORDER BY PRICE ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it again shown 125 value even i try by DESC order but it could not show 50 it shown 95.

Comment: Are you sure that your column data type is integer??

Comment: No its varchar(50). is it problem ?

Comment: Yes, This is only your problem. Change it as integer.

Comment: o brother thank you so much ... its working now!! i will keep it for next time thanks..

Comment: Welcome, If it works and solved your problem than accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `where` condition also. It filters rows first then `apply/Select` `columns` and `min`. I am sure that your where condition pull out row with price 50 and that's why min is coming as 125 instead of 50

Answer (score 0):

Please execute your query like,We need to convert into interger

mysql_query("SELECT ID, EID, COMMISSION, MIN(CONVERT(PRICE, SIGNED INTEGER)) as PRICE FROM `tickets` WHERE EID='$EID_UPcoMing' AND STATUS='1'");